# Не работает пример по UART в stm32f0

Tags: stm32, uart

Не работает прием по UART на stm32f030f4p6. Сам UART инициализирую так:

```
    void initUART(void)
{
    __HAL_RCC_USART1_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();
    huart.Instance = USART1;
    huart.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
    huart.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    huart.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    huart.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
    huart.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
    huart.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
    huart.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    huart.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    HAL_UART_Init(&huart);
    DMA1_Channel2->CCR &= ~(1 << 0);//Disable channel 2
    hdma.Instance = DMA1_Channel2;
    hdma.Init.Direction = DMA_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH;
    hdma.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
    hdma.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
    HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma);

    DMA1_Channel2->CCR |= (1 << 1);//Set transfer complete interrupt
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel2_3_IRQn, 2, 0); //Set the lowest priority for DMA interput
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel2_3_IRQn); //Enable DMA TCIE

    USART1->CR3 |= (1 << 7); //Enable DMA transmitet by DMAT
    USART1->CR2 |= (1 << 23);//Enable RTOEN
    USART1->CR1 |= (1 << 26);//Enable RTOIE
    USART1->RTOR |= 0x7FFFF;//Set 20 bits timeout duration
    USART1->CR1 |= (1 << 5); //Enable RXNE IT
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(USART1_IRQn, 1, 0); //Set the middle priority for USART interput
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_IRQn); //Enable usart rxne and rtof it
    USART1->CR1 |= (1 << 0); //Enable USART1
}
```

Пин PA9/10 Конфигурирую так:

```
//Set PA9 as UART TX
  gtd.Alternate = GPIO_AF1_USART1;
  gtd.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  gtd.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9;
  gtd.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &gtd);
  //Set PA10 as UART RX
  gtd.Alternate = GPIO_AF1_USART1;
  gtd.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  gtd.Pin = GPIO_PIN_10;
  gtd.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &gtd);
```

Без подтяжек. Отправка работает как надо, а вот принимать байты микросхема в упор не хочет(проверял логическим анализатором, проблема точно не в usb\uart конвертере. Все настройки в регистрах на месте, в ISR регистре бит RXNE и соотвествующее прерывание не выставляются). 
Пожалуйста, подскажите, что я делаю не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заменил пины PA10/PA9 НА PA2/PA3 из за коллизий с I2C1, и все сразу же заработало. В чем была причина я не нашел.